# MIMIC model in lavaan not identified

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm trying to estimate a MIMIC model in lavaan. When I estimate it without intercepts, standard errors can be computed, but when I try it with intercepts, the standard errors cannot be computed. It shows this error message:

```
1: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
    not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
    identified.
```

What should I do about it when I need the intercepts for the latent variable and for the indicators? Is there something I should have specified?

Thank you very much for your help!

Here I provide the model syntax and the path diagram:

```
mimic <- '
SE =~ GDP + M1
SE ~ Tax_dir + Freedom + Unemployment
Tax_dir ~~ Freedom + Unemployment
Freedom ~~ Unemployment
SE ~ 1
GDP ~ 1
M1 ~ 1
'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do about it when I need the intercepts for the latent variable and for the indicators?

Not sure why you would, since the latent variable's mean is arbitrary.  The effects-coding identification constraint would do the trick ([Little et al., 2006](https://doi.org/10.1207/s15328007sem1301_3)), although it is just as arbitrary as any other constraint, despite the misleading title.  In the case of only 2 reflective indicators, the factor mean would just be the average of the 2 indicator means, and the indicator means would be deviations around that "grand" mean.

```
GDP ~ m2*1 
M1  ~ m3*1

m2 == -1*m3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is very helpful. I have one more question: What if I had one more indicator? How should I constrain it correctly? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can read the article I linked to.  The general principle is that one of the intercepts is constrained to be -1 times the sum of the remaining intercepts (by definition, that constrains the average intercept to 0 per factor).  I applied the same idea to CFAs of generalizability theory, with example lavaan syntax, published open access: https://doi.org/10.3390/psych3020011